# How to check all radios by type?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have four `<input type"radio">` elements. How to check it on jQuery and alert when the elements are not checked by user?

Elements are in a `<div id"p1">` tags.

Answer (score 2):

This is to check all:

```
$('#p1 input[type=radio]').attr("checked", "checked");
```

This to check if all are unchecked:

```
if ($('#p1 input[type=radio]:checked').length == 0) {
    // alert here
}
```

This to check if one or more are unchecked:

```
if ($('#p1 input[type=radio]:checked').length < 4) {
        // alert here
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `.attr("checked")` you should use [`.prop("checked")`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: @gdoron: `.prop()` was introduced in jQuery 1.6 and the documentation strongly encourages you to use this to check the whether a radio/checkbox/option is *currently* checked/selected.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to check whether or not your radio buttons are checked.

You can select the radio buttons using an "[attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)" selector, and then [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the matched set to contain only unchecked radio buttons:

```
var uncheckedRadios = $("input[type='radio']").filter(function() {
    return !this.checked
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$("input[type='radio']").attr("checked","checked") will check all your radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='radio']:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    alert($(this).next().html());
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/nAB4T/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

```
var sQuestions = '';
$("input[type='radio']:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    sQuestions += $(this).next().html() + "\n";
});
alert(sQuestions);
```

Also see my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/nAB4T/2/).

=== UPDATE ===

Use `.attr('id')` instead of `.html()` to get the id instead of the text. Also see my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/nAB4T/12/).

I can't find the `div`s in your form, put one after each `input type="radio"`.

Comment: And see please, how to integrate it to my form: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977563/how-to-disable-tha-form-before-it-checked

Comment: Thank's! I have multiple radios in all groups. Id is here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the elements not checked like this :

```
    var uncheckedRadios = $("input[type='radio']").filter(function() {
Foo();
});
```

For each you find you can for example show a hidden label next to the elements. This label says something like "Warning, not checked". Or in the bottom of page, you can show the list of not checked radio buttons in a Red area..

Do this in the Foo() function..